# Getting jframe panel dimensions java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Pretty simple, I'm trying to figure out the jframe panel dimensions but whenever I get the dimensions it provides me with my screen dimensions, not the window dimensions. I have tried a multitude of options and have tried searching for a while yet I haven't been able to find any real solution that would work with the program provided here.

Source code:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame{

    JButton button;

    boolean on = false;
    
    public Window(){    
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
        int screenWidth = screenSize.width;

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(screenWidth,screenHeight);
        this.setLayout(null);   

        Dimension size = this.getSize();
        
        int frameHeight = size.height;
        int frameWidth = size.width;
    
        System.out.printf("Frame Height: %d\nFrame Width: %d\n", frameHeight, frameWidth);

        button = new JButton();
        if (on){
            configButton(button, Color.GREEN, "On");
        } else {
            configButton(button, Color.RED, "Off");
        }   
        button.setBounds(frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2, 100, 100);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        on = !on;
                System.out.printf("On is: %b\n", on);
                if (on){
                    configButton(button, Color.GREEN, "On");
                } else {
                    configButton(button, Color.RED, "Off");
                }
                button.setLocation(frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2);
                System.out.printf("Frame Height: %d\nFrame Width: %d\n", frameHeight, frameWidth);
                }
            });
        
        this.add(button);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void configButton(JButton b, Color c, String s){
        b.setBackground(c);
        b.setOpaque(true);
        b.setText(s);
    }

}
```

And then the executing file if that's needed

```java
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Window();
    }        
}
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to figure out the jframe panel dimensions"* . . . ***Why?*** I smell an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

you are always printing out the size of the first time your GUI launched.
i hope this would solve your problem:

```
System.out.printf("Frame Height: %d\nFrame Width: %d\n", getContentPane().getHeight(),getContentPane().getWidth());
```